# Как правильно найти количество цифр заданного целого числа?

Tags: c++

Мой код проходит по всем тестам на `90%`, не проходит один тест.
Проблему почему не проходит на все `100` - не нашёл..

Условие: Найти количество цифр заданного целого числа `number`.

Пример: вводим число `37` должно вывести число `2`.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long long int number = 0;
    int result = 0;
    std::cin >> number;
    while(number != 0) {
        number /= 10;
        result++;
    }
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Подумайте, что произойдет, если заданное число не помещается в long long int.

Comment: А что будет если ввести ноль?

Comment: коду не важно число отрицательное или нет. Просто напишите один цикл:  while(number != 0) {
        number /= 10;
        ++result;
    }   или можно сразу вывести результат: cout << static_cast<int>(log10(abs(number))) + 1;

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, спасибо, но всеравно 90%

Comment: @EOF, Если ввести 0, будет 0.

Comment: @user7860670, будет просто выводить максимальное количество цыфр при long long int - ето 19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почти наверняка в том единственном тесте вводится `0`.

> Делать условие именно на то, что юзер введёт цифру 0, и нужно вывести 1. Както колхозно, как можно реализовать без етого?

Делать отдельно условие нормально, но если есть желание сделать без условия, то можно и без него:

```
cin >> number;

int result = 1;
while (number /= 10) ++result;

cout << result;
```

Comment: Делать условие именно на то, что юзер введёт цифру 0, и нужно вывести 1. Както колхозно, как можно реализовать без етого?

Comment: @Denys, дополнил.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Если вводите с консоли, то и не нужно рассматривать последовательность цифр как число. Можно просто читать и "выбрасывать" символы_цифры, с увеличением счетчика:

```
int res{};         
while (isdigit(getchar())) ++res;
printf("%d", res);
```

Вариантов решения  много.
Задание должно четко выразить что критично и каким образом задается объект. Потому что "задано число" наталкивает написать функцию с целочисленным аргументом, а пример рождает вопрос "откуда вводится?"...

Comment: Неправильно если будет вводиться что-то в духе `042`.

Comment: Уточнить продробнее условия я не могу ето полное условие, и число с плавающей точкой нельзя писать, число же челое..